# MacBook: Outlook reading pane does not show attached files. You can see the paperclip, but not the attachments

Tags: mac, attachments

Saw this problem reported in 2017 and tried the recommended procedure that included terminal commands but to no avail. Also saw a remedy that didn't seem to work from a 2019 post.

I can see the paperclip, indicating an attachment was sent, but the attachment is not visible. The only way an attachment can be made visible is by Forwarding the email. The email does not have to be forwarded, but starting the process makes the attachment visible. It is an inconvenient work-around.

Current MacOS version is 16.68. Is there a fix? Seems like a long-time and/or recurrent issue.

Comment: Can we have the link to the procedure you tried, so we do not repeat it. Have you tried to disable your antivirus software?